# Downloading a .ts or .m3u8 video using youtube-dl or any other CLI

Tags: gratis, video, web-browser

I am downloading videos from a website using the Video DownloadHelper Firefox extension. Recently I encountered an issue where the audio video is out of sync and the video is playing in a slow mode. Not sure what could be the issue. Is there any other extension that works like Video DownloadHelper? Or will it be possible to use youtube-dl or another CLI tool to download a video?

**Observations:**
I do see a `.m3u8` URL loaded in the Network tab. There are several URLs ending with `.ts` Not sure which one can be used to download the video.

Comment: You want to download videos only from youtube? Should it be only plugin for firefox or also some standalone application?

Comment: No, it's not youtube. It can be a standalone application. But I need to log in to the website to watch the videos. So I am not sure if a non-plugin application will be able to do it or noto

Comment: And which site is it, if I am alowed to ask?